# How to pass IHttpContextAccessor to Serilog Enricher by Configuration

Tags: asp.net-core, serilog

I wanted to add httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.TraceIdentifier to every log entry, so created a custom enricher, also i have it setup using Serilog.Settings.Configuration, but not sure how do i pass HttpContextAccessor to the Enricher through config

```
{
    "Enrich": ["FromLogContext", "LogTraceid"],
    "WriteTo": [{
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
            "path": "App_Data/Logs/App.log",
            "rollingInterval": "Day",
            "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [{Level:u3}] [{TraceId}] [{RequestId}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}"
        }
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This example works fine

Got it from this repo

https://github.com/JohnLTaylor/Serilog.Enrichers.TraceIdentifier/blob/master/src/Serilog.Enrichers.TraceIdentifier/Enrichers/TraceIdentifierEnricher.cs

```
class TraceIdentifierEnricher : ILogEventEnricher
{
    private const string TraceIdentifierPropertyName = "TraceIdentifier";
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor;

    public TraceIdentifierEnricher() : this(new HttpContextAccessor())
    {
    }

    public TraceIdentifierEnricher(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor)
    {
        _contextAccessor = contextAccessor;
    }

    public void Enrich(LogEvent logEvent, ILogEventPropertyFactory propertyFactory)
    {
        var property = propertyFactory.CreateProperty(TraceIdentifierPropertyName, _contextAccessor.HttpContext?.TraceIdentifier ?? "-");
        logEvent.AddOrUpdateProperty(property);
    }
}

public static class TraceIdentifierLoggerConfigurationExtensions
{
    public static LoggerConfiguration WithTraceIdentifier(
       this LoggerEnrichmentConfiguration enrichmentConfiguration)
    {
        if (enrichmentConfiguration == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(enrichmentConfiguration));
        return enrichmentConfiguration.With<TraceIdentifierEnricher>();
    }
}
```

Also ensure you have registered [IHttpContextAccessor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-5.0#use-httpcontext-from-custom-components) in the services collection

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Running this, the constructor with the `IHttpContextAccessor` param seems to never used via the asp.net dependency injection.  But rather `TraceIdentifierEnricher` is constructed *one time* from the `Program.Main` with the empty constructor (creating the `HttpContextAccessor` itself).  It seems to work.  Is that the standard practice?  Looking at this repo (https://github.com/trenoncourt/serilog-enrichers-aspnetcore-httpcontext), he seems to try and do something much more complicated.  Know Pros/Cons of each method?

Comment: services.AddHttpContextAccessor(); ..was the problem for me ! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

If you use [Serilog.AspNetCore](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore#serilogaspnetcore---), `TraceId` and `RequestId` are automatically included.

[image: Seq]

Check the code samples: https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore/tree/dev/samples

Comment: Thank you for the reply, i also have some custom logic inside the enricher using HttpContext request query string, so i would like to know how that can be achieved